# XSl and XML conversition for IE11

Tags: javascript, java, xml, xslt

This code was working in IE 5 but not working with IE11.

JSP Code:

```
function doTranslate(th,_th,repName,_id){

    var trans= XmlXslXform(savRepXsl,_th,'reportName',repName); 
    document.daily_report.criteria_Id.value=_id;

    try{
        lastRow.style.background="#FAFAFA";         
    }catch(obj){}                                   

    th.style.background     =   "#DDDDDD";                      
    lastRow                 =   th;                         

    selectDesc.innerHTML    =   trans.xml;                      
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
function XmlXslXform(xmlIsland, xslIsland, paramName, paramValue)
{
    var objxsltTemplate;
    var objxsltProcessor;
    var objXSLT2; //FreeThreadedDOMDocument

    try
    { 
        objXSLT2 = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0");
        objXSLT2.async = false;
        objXSLT2.validateOnParse = false;
        objXSLT2.loadXML(xslIsland.xml);
        objxsltTemplate = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XSLTemplate.3.0");
        objxsltTemplate.stylesheet = objXSLT2;
        objxsltProcessor = objxsltTemplate.createProcessor();
        objxsltProcessor.input = xmlIsland;
        objxsltProcessor.addParameter(paramName, paramValue);

        objxsltProcessor.transform();

        return objxsltProcessor.output;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        / error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a `try` with an empty `catch`? If you want to get some indication which error occurs then log that error. But generally XML data islands (which I suppose you use with `xslIsland.xml`) are not supported in newer versions of IE, you need to load the XML using `XMLHttpRequest` or using the `load` method from a URL e.g. `objXSLT2.load('sheet.xsl')`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Martin. And My catch block was not empty, i just didn't shared here as it was customized error.